# Cannot retrieve data from controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is my javascript code:

```
<script> 
    $(function() {

        $( "#name" ).autocomplete({
            source: "http://localhost:3000/shirts/autocomplete",
            autoFocus: false,
            minLength: 0,
            select: function(event,ui){
                document.getElementById("name").value = ui.item.value;
                document.getElementById("autoc").submit();
                var myname = $("#name").val();
                $.ajax({
                    url:"http://localhost:3000/shirts/show",
                    type:"GET",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data: ??
                }); 
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

What should I set my data field in order to set the variable "myname" value to it?

Comment: Show your contoller code

Comment: What do you want to achieve using this code?

Comment: I have a app with search functionality. I want to take the input from user in the form and display the result. I works fine if I dont use autocomplete. But when I try using auto-complete it gives the following error "Missing template shirts/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/home/aws003/Desktop/Raghuveer/Shirt/app/views" * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/kaminari-0.15.1/app/views" "

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
    url:"http://localhost:3000/shirts/show",
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    data: { q: myname }
});
```

Now in your controller you can read the value of `q` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

what is wrong in using `$("#name").val()`

```
$.ajax({
              url:"http://localhost:3000/shirts/show",
              type:"GET",
              dataType:"json",
              data:$("#name").val()
        });
```

Comment: Please do not beg for download reasons. It is going against the general ethic on the site.

Comment: @LaszloPapp `It is going against the general ethic on the site.` Why?

Comment: @dfsq: because that is how the site works! Moderators explicitly remove comments that beg for downvote reasons. We really do not want begging comments after each unexplained downvote on the site.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar - he must have intended to write "downVOTE" reason. Spellchecker autocorrection gone too far maybe.

Comment: that said, I am not your downvoter, but I could suggest that as now your answer seems more a question. Maybe rewording it should help "You can use (code). Is there any special reason the above isn't enough in your case? If required leave a notice and I will try to provide some more info".

Comment: @SPArchaeologist: yes, that is a typo, and I am sure Milind was aware of that, too, but the noise is growing, oh yeah!